# Did Odo create his communicator or hide it?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

Odo has a working communicator:

[image: Odo's communicator]

Is that a part of himself (like his clothes)? Or is it real but he conceals it?

I imagine it is the latter (would be hard for him to create) but I don't know if it is ever addressed.

Comment: According to [Memory Alpha](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Odo#Shapeshifting_nature_and_ability), he *did* create his own combadge but on at least one occasion used a real one. Perhaps the answer is then *both*?

Comment: Interesting - where is that screenshot from? The face is off, like this was from a makeup test or something. it definitely doesn't look like the normal Odo makeup.

Comment: This subject has been discussed on [reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/startrek/comments/2sz0zf/what_the_hell_does_odo_do_with_his_communicator/).

Comment: @Omegacron: bit late, but I've [found it](http://en.memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Odo)!

Comment: @Wikis maybe it's just the lighting in that scene, but the cheekbones are more prominent and the nose has more detail than usual. At any rate, I'm not sure it's polite to ask Odo where he sticks his communicator when he changes.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It is real. I remember at least one scene in which he took off the communicator and set it down on his desk in the security office because he didn't want anyone to know where he was going.

Although it does still beg the question of what he does with it when he shape shifts. My guess would be that he just carries it inside himself in whatever shape he creates.

Comment: Can you find out which episode and link to it?

Comment: Pedantry: The question of what Odo does with the communicator when shape shifting is not "begged", it's raised. http://begthequestion.info/

Comment: @Wikis Odo's page on memory alpha makes a [reference](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Odo#Shapeshifting_nature_and_ability) (4th paragraph) to it being in the episode [Invasive Procedures](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Invasive_Procedures_(episode)), but I don't see it in the episode summary.

Comment: @DaveMG - You ol' prescriptivist, you. :)

Comment: @Izkata: indeed, I added the link myself, above, in the comments to the question. But since, as you say, the episode summary made no mention of it, I added the question and link here.

Comment: @neilfein: :) I just like to start fights over matters of no import.

Comment: @DaveMG - Heh. Matters of language are important, and always interest me - and [others](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/305/161) as [well](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/38394/161).

Comment: @Izkata I just watched the episode Invasive Procedures on netflix. Odo, Quark and Bashir are held at gunpoint, one of the bad guys tells another to remove their comm badges and a girl reaches out and takes all their badges. After that they make Odo get into the container. In the scene you directly see the girl removing the badge from Odo.

Comment: @AlanBarber Interesting, that does mean there's at least two such episodes, 'cause I'm pretty sure I do remember the scene you mentioned in the answer.  I have the feeling the episode involved either Lwaxana Troi, or someone else from back when Odo was security officer on Terok Nor

Comment: @Questioner:   (Hello from the future.)  That site really doesn't get it right.   People don't generally use "beg the question" to mean "raise the question".   It's more like the consequence of the proposition is so obvious or important that it "begs" that the resulting question be asked.    Even in the "incorrect" usage it is not "beg" == "raise".   It's "beg" == "beg to be raised".

Comment: @ThePopMachine, [ObEGS](http://www.egscomics.com/comic/2016-03-28-checking-in).

Comment: @ThePopMachine, I understand people are using "begs the question" to mean "begs for the question to be raised", but that doesn't make it any more correct to replace an existing saying with a different meaning. If one insists on using "beg", then one should say "begs *for* the question".

Comment: @Questioner:   I don't have a problem with it.   Not only are prepositions pretty fluid in expressions, but it could be interpreted like this:    *Boy, leaving that cake unattended on the counter really begs, "Eat me!"*  which is the same as *Boy, leaving that cake unattended really begs the invitation "Eat me!"*.   That's not any grammatically different than the "incorrect" usages of *begs the question*.

Answer (score 6):

In the episode "*Broken Link*", when Odo is losing control of his shape shifting, there are a couple of shots where you can see his communicator is partially liquefied, indicating it is actually part of him, and not a device.

Comment: Welcome to SFF! This is a nice first answer, it would be better if you included an image/video of this happening though.

Answer (score 3):

Odo stated that if he became a rock, all sensors would indicate he is a rock. This means that when he becomes a rock, he is actually a rock, and not just a facsimile of the rock (i.e. the composition is also a rock). Nothing says he can't actually become a complex piece of electronics like a communicator. He can turn into *fire*. Why not a communicator, with practice?

Comment: Can you please add a reference for where he said that and when he turned into fire?

Comment: I'm not convinced that, just because he can become a rock, he could necessarily become a communicator. He can't do the contours of a human face properly, why should he be able to become something as complicated as a communicator? Wouldn't that require him to know how every internal circuit / line of code was constructed?

Comment: @Wikis Maybe Larry has a non-canon source. After Laas showed Odo that changelings can exist as fire, there is nothing in the show to even suggest that Odo tried it for himself.

Answer (score 1):

In episode 3 "[Past Prologue](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Past_Prologue_%28episode%29)", Odo becomes a mouse. So he can replicate more than just "dead" matter.

I just started watching the series on Netflix and happened to catch it when he was observing the Klingon women. Most likely the communicator is held within the shape he has assumed at the time.

Comment: This answer appears to be a comment on @AaronDegulla's answer

Comment: But was he a mouse or just a shapeshifter who looks like a mouse? i.e. he could replicate the shape of a communicator but I don't think he could make it work

Comment: But the mouse worked, right? Why would he be able to create a working mouse but only a broken communicator? How does that work?

Answer (score 0):

I have no reference but AFAIR, Odo can only replicate "dead" matter (like a container) or "simple" machines (maybe a piston or a sliding door) - not complex electronics.

He can look like a wall monitor (and probably even shift the colors on his surface and respond to touch, especially when they look as simple as the command interfaces ones used in Star Trek) but he can't send commands over a wire or receive a TV stream or the like.

Comment: I'd hardly call turning into a "solid" as the changlings call it "dead matter".  I know what you were trying to say, but you probably had a bad choice of words.